# Android file storage and sharing

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

In my Android Project, there is an audio file (`sample.mp3`) in the `raw` folder. Here I have two questions:

1. How to store that file in the app's internal storage? (I checked many documentations, they are talking about how to create a new file in the directory)

   But I need to store an already existing file in the directory.
2. How to generate `contentUri` for that file using `FilepPovider`, after storing it in internal storage?

Comment: If you want to move it to the file system, the easiest thing is to put it in assets rather than raw, then move it over to the filesystem by reading it from assets and writing it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you provide a code snippet if possible?